# Is there any way to convert String[] into List<AyrrayList<>> in java?

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, collections

I need to convert this string array

```
String[] myStringArray0 = {"FTMORGANIZATION_NAME","FTMOBJECTNUMBER","FTMCONTAINERTYPE","FTMCONTAINER"};
```

Into

```
List<ArrayList<String>>
```

where all the "FTMORGANIZATION_NAME","FTMOBJECTNUMBER","FTMCONTAINERTYPE","FTMCONTAINER" goes into ArrayList and that goes into List object.

Can anybody have suggestion?

Comment: So every `String` has to be in separate list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] myStringArray0 = {"FTMORGANIZATION_NAME","FTMOBJECTNUMBER","FTMCONTAINERTYPE","FTMCONTAINER"};

List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(Arrays.asList(myStringArray0));
```

[asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Arrays.asList` method to create an `ArrayList`, then simply add it to a `List`

```
String[] myStringArray0 = {"FTMORGANIZATION_NAME","FTMOBJECTNUMBER","FTMCONTAINERTYPE","FTMCONTAINER"};

ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myStringArray0));
List<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(arraylist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate ove the array and add the srings to the list.

```
int index = 0;
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
List<ArrayList<String>> listlist = new ArrayList<>();

for (index = 0; index < mystringArray0.length, index++)
{
   myList.add(mystringArray0[index]); 
}
listlist.add(mylist);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `for` loop and add each element of the String array to ArrayList.

Ex :`ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();`

`for(int i=0; i<myStringArray0.length; i++) 
 {
    values.add(myStringArray0[i]);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply like below i posted,I hope it will help you

```
String[] myStringArray = {"FTMORGANIZATION_NAME", "FTMOBJECTNUMBER", "FTMCONTAINERTYPE", "FTMCONTAINER"};
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(Arrays.toString(myStringArray));
        System.out.println("list : " + list.toString());
list : [[FTMORGANIZATION_NAME, FTMOBJECTNUMBER, FTMCONTAINERTYPE, FTMCONTAINER]]
```